# What's this anime on the DVD cover in part of this photo?

Tags: identification-request

A friend of mine linked me a following meme picture:

[image]

**I would like to know what's the name of the DVD he's holding in his hands.**

I think I've once seen that DVD cover he is holding in his hands but for the life of me can't recall anything from it. No name, nothing.

For some reason this thing started to bother me and so I'm wondering does anyone recognize the anime he's holding in his hands. But to be honest not sure if it's even an anime. I believe it was some kind of OVA but am not sure.

After searching for it for sometime I couldn't find anything. Hopefully someone knows better than me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Searching for the image resulted in this title **影のセクハリスト ～孕ませ王位継承騒動～**, which roughly translates to *Sexual Harasser of the Dark ~ The Impregnation Mayhem for Throne Succession ~*

Here is [a clearer version of the cover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miHk1.jpg) **(NSFW)**.

Here is the link to [official website](http://www.lilith-soft.com/lilith/product40.html) **(NSFW)** and [its entry on vndb](http://vndb.org/v7705).

It seems to be a eroge, not an anime, though.

The site describes it as a "magic school slapstick love comedy".

Comment: The image matches up, but could you perhaps give [a bit more detail](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/998/2604) about the anime in question?

Comment: I am not so much proficient in japanse to provide a "readable" traduction of the site I linked to (which corresponds to the original company that produced the game). I do not know the game myself.

Comment: Hmmm it does seem relatively obscure (as an anime I mean) in the English speaking world (at least from a quick search with the kanji). At any rate, good catch!

Comment: More information about this is available at http://vndb.org/v7705. That said, it's a pretty standard nukige without any particular notability outside of this meme, so I don't think a lot more needs to be said here.

Comment: *"A real female ofcause, smells, is dirty...ofcause because its a human being, it has lots of things. So we have this anime, isn't it clean and pretty"*, until you realize that @LoganM 's link has it tagged to have Bukkake, which i assume smells, is dirty and hardly not clean or pretty